# Scope that cooperates with a has many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, activerecord

I have a User model that has_many documents and a Document model that belongs to a user, like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :documents, dependent: :destroy
end

class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

And I have a `boolean` field on Documents named `archived`. I can access all the documents that belong to a user through:
    `@user = User.first`
    `@user.documents`.
But what I want to do is create a scope on the User model to display all the documents that belong to that user and have an archived value of true. I could just use a model method, but I would like to figure out how to scope it. Something along the lines of `scope, -> {documents.where(archived: true)}`. How would I do something like that with a has_many relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best qualities of ActiveRecord scopes is that they compose with each other, and with relationships.  Add this scope inside Document like so:

```
class Document
  scope :archived { where(archived: true) }
end
```

Then this code will work as you expect:

```
@user = User.first
@user.documents.archived
```

An additional technique to be aware of, as your scopes become more complex, is that you can create a shorthand for them in places of frequent access.

```
class User
  def archived_documents
    documents.archived
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To kind of answer my own question, you can also use a `has_many` relationship with a where clause. This is in the User Model:

```
has_many archived_documents, -> { where(archived: true) }, class_name: 'Document'
```

Comment: You can also define methods on the association in the middle of declaring it:  has_many :documents { def complex_scope; archived.some_other_scope; end }  Check it out!